# Different Headers but Same Footer for Each Section

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

How would I create a document that has two sections where the headers are different but the footers are the same?

For example,
I would have the first section be labeled "Header 1" and the second section be labeled "Header 2".
The footer for both of those sections would be the same. In this case, "Author: John Apples."

I am working in MS Excel since I want to import some data from a sheet.

I tried `DifferentHeaderFirstPageHeaderFooter = True` but that applies to both the header and footer.
Also, I don't believe I am creating separate sections so it would be nice to have that feature implemented since I plan to add more sections that would have different headers.

```vb
'Create a new Doc
Set myDocument = WordApp.Documents.Add
WordApp.Visible = True
WordApp.Activate

'Set Landscape Orientation
myDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 1

'Set Margins
myDocument.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 26
myDocument.PageSetup.TopMargin = 26
myDocument.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 36
myDocument.PageSetup.RightMargin = 36

myDocument.Styles("Footer").Font.Size = 9
myDocument.Styles("Header").Font.Size = 18
myDocument.Styles("Header").Font.Color = RGB(0, 98, 155)

Set objSelection = WordApp.Selection

'Creating the header
objSelection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore "Header 1"
objSelection.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InsertBefore "Header 2"

'Add Footer and Page Numbers
objSelection.Sections(1).Footers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore "Author: John Apples"
objSelection.Sections(1).Footers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InsertBefore "Author: John Apples"
        
objSelection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).PageNumbers.ShowFirstPageNumber = True
objSelection.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add FirstPage:=True
        
objSelection.Font.Name = "Arial"
objSelection.Font.Size = 12
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 98, 155)
        
myDocument.Sections.First.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
```

These two photos are what I would like the end product to look like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the text that appears in the page header appears in the body of the document as a heading you only need one header containing a StyleRef field - see http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm. If you really need a new section you need to add a Section break - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertbreak and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbreaktype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite simply by giving the document a 'different first page' layout (as you've done), using:

```
Set myDocument = WordApp.Documents.Add
With myDocument
  'Set Landscape Orientation
  .PageSetup.Orientation = wdOrientLandscape
  'Set Margins
  .PageSetup.BottomMargin = 26
  .PageSetup.TopMargin = 26
  .PageSetup.LeftMargin = 36
  .PageSetup.RightMargin = 36
  'Set Style Fonts
  With .Styles("Normal").Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .Size = 12
    .Color = RGB(0, 98, 155)
  End With
  .Styles("Footer").Font.Size = 9
  With .Styles("Header").Font
    .Size = 18
    .Color = RGB(0, 98, 155)
  End With
  'Create the layout
  With .Sections.First
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    'Creating the header
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
      .Style = "Header"
      .Text = "Header 1"
    End With
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.InsertBefore "Header 2"
   'Add Footer and Page Numbers
    With .Footers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
      With .Range
        .Style = "Footer"
        .Text = "Author: John Apples"
      End With
    End With
    With .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      With .Range
        .Style = "Footer"
        .Text = "Author: John Apples"
      End With
      .PageNumbers.Add FirstPage:=False
    End With
  End With
End With
```

Note that the document doesn't need to be visible or active for any of this to take place, and that you don't need to select anything.

Then, to add a new section with a different footer, you could insert the following code before the final 'End With'. The primary page header will carry over into the new Section and, by unlinking the new Section from the previous one, you can update the new Section's footer.

```
  'Add New Section with its own Footer and Page Numbers
  .Range.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  With .Sections.Last
    With .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      .LinkToPrevious = False
      .Range.Text = "Author: Betty Blue"
      .PageNumbers.Add FirstPage:=False
    End With
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
  End With
```

Conversely, to add a new section with a different header, you could insert the following code before the final 'End With'. The primary page footer will carry over into the new Section and, by unlinking the new Section from the previous one, you can update the new Section's header.

```
  'Add New Section with its own Header
  .Range.Characters.Last.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakNextPage
  With .Sections.Last
    With .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
      .LinkToPrevious = False
      .Range.Text = "Header 3"
    End With
    .PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it seemed to help me understand a bit on how it should be structured but still didn't give me my desired output. I have updated my question to include screenshots of what I am looking for.

Comment: The first macro in my answer does as you described and as your screenshots depict. The second code block shows how you might then add a new Section with the same header but a different footer. The third code block (which I've now added) shows how you might add a new Section with a different header but the same footer.